# Accessing classes of dependent modules of dependent modules in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a structure in an android app using gradle like,

```
module A:
    dependencies{ 
    module B
    }
module B:{
   dependencies{
   module C
   }
module C:{
   dependencies{
   module D
   }
```

Are these dependencies transitive? How can I access the classes of module D in module A directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit : same thing with `D`

`C` is a transitive dependency of `A`

Your ide should allow you to directly use classes of `C` in `A` but it's a bad practice. If `A` really needs `C`, it should declare it as a direct dependency

```
module A:
    dependencies { 
       module B
       module C
       module D
}
```

Comment: done, same thing, just add `D` as a dependency if `A`

Comment: No, I want to know if it can be done using transitivity.

Comment: It will work but if a module really needs a dependency, it should declare it

Comment: Why is this considered a bad practice?

Comment: It explained in these 2 links : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/320128/is-it-better-to-rely-on-transitive-dependencies-or-explicitly-declare-them/320151 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47260901/should-i-rely-on-transitive-dependencies-in-maven-if-they-come-from-other-sub-mo